# save increase int as multiple core data entities

Tags: swift, core-data, integer, relationship

In my swift code below I am trying to save ints to core data. Every time a user hits a button a new int is created. So if the user hits the button twice there are know 2 int entities in core data. My code below is having a runtime error and I dont know how to solve it.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zf6i.png)

```
      var pageNumber = 0
        var itemName : [NSManagedObject] = []

   func enterData() {
    
    let appDeldeaget = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    
    
    
    let context = appDeldeaget.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    
    
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Player", in: context)
    

    let theTitle = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
 
    
    theTitle.setValue(pageNumber, forKey: "positon")
    
    do {
        try context.save()
        itemName.append(theTitle)
        pageNumber += 1
        
     
    }
    catch {
        
    }
    self.theScores.reloadData()
    
 
            
  
    positionTextField.text = ""
    positionTextField.resignFirstResponder()
  
    
    
}
```

Comment: What is your runtime error?

Comment: You should at least print the thrown error in the `catch` even if don't have any other error handling. `catch let error as NSError { print(error.localizedDescription) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are introducing a few complications that might be causing the issue.

First, *if I understood your purpose*, the `itemName` should not be an array of `NSManagedObject`, but rather an array of `Player`. Also, creating the `theTitle` can be simplified.

Try this instead of the code you proposed:

```
      var pageNumber = 0

      // If I understand correctly, you should have an array of Players
      var itemName : [Player] = []

   func enterData() {
    
    let appDeldeaget = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    
    let context = appDeldeaget.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    // Simpler way to create a new Core Data object
    let theTitle = Player(context: context)

    // Simpler way to set the position attribute
    theTitle.position = pageNumber    // pageNumber must be of type Int64, otherwise use Int64(pageNumber)
    
    do {
        try context.save()
        itemName.append(theTitle)
        pageNumber += 1
    } catch {
        // handle errors
    }
    
    // rest of the code

}
```

Comment: I am getting a error stating value of type 'Player' has no member 'position'

Comment: @sillymilly That’s because it is correctly spelled in the answer but it should be written “positon” to not get an error since that is how you spelled it in your model